# Django one-to-one field reverse update

Tags: python, django, one-to-one

I am having an issue saving reverse object in a one-to-one relation. According to Django doc everything works fine once you use save() method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

However my situation is different :

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    aObject = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am creating multiples B object first and save them to the database. Then I create multiple A objects, map them with the corresponding B objet. Then I save the A objects using bulk_create() and finally save the modified B objects with save().

I get an error :

```
ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'aObject'.
```

It seems that using a bulk_create on A objects does not perform some operations that save() would have performed.

How can I go through this issue ? (I need to use a bulk_create for performance reasons)

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the code where you create the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `bulk_create`, Django does not get the new object's primary keys. Therefore it is not possible to use your new objects as values for one-to-one fields, many-to-many fields or foreign keys.

Django 1.10 will support setting primary keys on objects created using `bulk_create()` for PostgreSQL. Until then, and with other database backends, I'm afraid you are out of luck.

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) for more information.